# Use accurate verbs to describe changes

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Because we don't know what happened between the two years, I shouldn't use words like "removed", or "demolished"? There might be a fire and the glasshouse might be destroyed by the fire.

I shouldn't use "changed", "converted", or "turned" either because the glasshouse and seats, and the water feature are completely different things.

The only word I can use is "replaced". Is this correct?

> To the right of the garden, the glasshouse and seats have been
> **replaced** by a water feature. (correct)

> To the right of the garden, the glasshouse and seats have been
> **removed/demolished** to make room for a water feature. (Incorrect)

> To the right of the garden, the glasshouse and seats have been **changed/turned/converted** into a water feature. (Incorrect)

However, the stage for musicians and the amphitheater for concerts, in essence, are the same things. So I can use "changed", "turned", "converted" or "transformed"?

> The stage for musicians on the left side of the park has been
> **changed/turned/converted/transformed** into an amphitheater for
> concerts.

I have trouble uploading the maps. Please click the link to see the maps.
https://snipboard.io/EUyt1W.jpg

Comment: So the question is: Was the stage converted into an amphitheatre (using much of the original material) or was it replaced by an amphitheatre (the stage was removed and a new amphitheatre built)  **There is no way that we can tell from the picture**.  Do you have photographs?  Where is this park?

Comment: @JamesK, this is a writing task for English learners. I want to use verbs accurately. I updated the link to the maps. Please check it again.

Comment: **Replaced** is the best option I can think of. It does imply something made by human agency, not e.g. wild plants growing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also say that the glasshouse has *given way to* or *given place to* a water feature. I wouldn't say that *removed* was wrong, because even if it was destroyed in a fire, the debris would still have had to be cleared away.

Yes, you could use any of the words you suggest for the stage. Even if the amphitheatre was a 'new build' and not an actual conversion, you can use them in a metaphorical sense to suggest that the stage was replaced with something having the same function.

Comment: Thank you, Kate. Do you agree that if the two things are completely different things, "change", "turned", "converted", and "transformed" cannot be used?  For example, it would be incorrect to say that the garden has been changed/turned/converted/transformed into a cafe. I was told I can use "changed" or "turned" but "converted" and "transformed" don't work.

Comment: _Conversion_ suggests that an existing building has been altered for a new purpose, _transformed_ that its appearance has changed dramatically. _Turned into_ and _changed into_ are a bit more vague; they could just mean that it is being used for a new purpose, or imply replacement.